# Laravel variable loses scope in query

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to query in the database but laravel variable is losing its scope and the query doesn't give any output .. i tried using whereRaw but it didn't work

```
 public function search_user(Request $r)
{
  try
  {


      if(JWTAuth::User()->role != 'Admin')
          return response()->json(['status'=>False,'error'=>'You do not have permission to Create User.Please Contact your admin for access.']);


      $search_type = $r->search_type;//Possible Values , email , userid , username , phone, role
      $search_text = strtolower($r->search_text);


      $limit = $r->limit;
      $offset = $r->offset;
      $role = JWTAuth::User()->role;

      $user = User::where($search_type,'Like','%'.$search_text.'%')->skip($offset)->take($limit)->toSql();
      $count_of_search = count($user);


      if($role == 'Admin')
          return response()->json(['status'=>true,'data'=>$user,'view_user'=>True,'add_user'=>True , 'edit_user'=>True,'delete_user'=>True,'total_users'=>$count_of_search],200);
      elseif($role == 'User')
          return response()->json(['status'=>true,'data'=>$user,'view_user'=>False,'add_user'=>False , 'edit_user'=>False,'delete_user'=>False,'total_users'=>$count_of_search],200);
      elseif($role == 'Developer')
          return response()->json(['status'=>true,'data'=>$user,'view_user'=>True,'add_user'=>False , 'edit_user'=>False,'delete_user'=>False,'total_users'=>$count_of_search],200);
  }


**Query Output**

"select * from `users` where `username` Like ? limit 5 offset 0"
```

Comment: What didn't work? What error are you getting? Please add more explanation to your code please. What variable is losing scope? Why didn't whereRaw not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the following line:

`$user = User::where($search_type,'Like','%'.$search_text.'%')->skip($offset)->take($limit)->toSql();`

By the line below:

`$user = User::where($search_type,'Like','%'.$search_text.'%')->skip($offset)->take($limit)->get();`

**Because:**

`toSql()` method return the sql query but `get()` method actually execute the query. Besides, if you want to count the number of user you can use the `count` method of collection. as below:

`$count_of_search = $user->count()`